# Aspect ratio between axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

Referencing [barcode_demo](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barcode_demo.html) example, with slight modification of adding an image:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, savefig, cm
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(500, 200)

axprops = dict(xticks=[], yticks=[])
barprops = dict(aspect='auto', cmap=cm.binary, interpolation='nearest')

fig = figure()

ax = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6], **axprops)
ax.imshow(img, **barprops)

x = np.array([img[y, :].sum() for y in xrange(img.shape[0])])
x = np.column_stack((x,) * 10).reshape(x.shape[0], 10)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.6], **axprops)
ax.imshow(x, **barprops)

x = np.array([img[:, x].sum() for x in xrange(img.shape[1])])
x = np.row_stack((x,) * 10).reshape(10, x.shape[0])
ax = fig.add_axes([0.3, 0.1, 0.6, 0.1], **axprops)
ax.imshow(x, **barprops)

savefig('auto.png')
```

results in image which does not respect aspect ration (as expected):

[image: auto.png]

If I set `aspect` parameter in `barprops` dict to "equal" (which seems like default value in matplotlib), I get this image:

[image: equal.png]

Is there easy way to plot image with respect to aspect ratio, and plot these two "barcodes" to match drawn image?

Answer (score 0):

The `aspect` kwarg for imshow sets the aspect ratio in data coordinates, not figure coordinates. The easiest thing for you to do would be to make the figure itself square. I can modify your code ever so slightly by changing the figure declaration to:

```
fig = figure(figsize=(7, 7))
```

and get

[image]

It would also be possible to do some math based on the aspect ratio of the figure and use that in your call to `fig.add_axes` so that the aspect ratio of the axes themselves is what you expect, but for this figure that would just leave you a lot of useless whitespace.